# systemd timer. several instance, different time?

Tags: systemd

I'm using the [btrfs-scrub@.timer](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/btrfs-scrub@.timer?h=packages/btrfs-progs) which is a timer with a template. (the argument represents the btrfs volume to scrub)

I need to scrub several volumes regularly but I'd like scrubs not to happen simultaneously. (e.g everyday a scrub, each day a different volume).

According to the documentation, you can only have [one argument per timer](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)

Is there a simple way to do that with systemd timers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the timer specifications for each unit using drop-in files, for example:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/btrfs-scrub@-.timer.d/OnCalendar.conf
[Timer]
OnCalendar=
OnCalendar=*-*-01 00:00:00
```

```
# /etc/systemd/system/btrfs-scrub@usr.timer.d/OnCalendar.conf
[Timer]
OnCalendar=
OnCalendar=*-*-10 00:00:00
```

```
# /etc/systemd/system/btrfs-scrub@var-lib.timer.d/OnCalendar.conf
[Timer]
OnCalendar=
OnCalendar=*-*-20 00:00:00
```

Comment: It solves my problem, thanks. Although, why do we have to add an empty `OnCalendar=` at the beginning of drop-in files?

Comment: Because `OnCalendar` can be specified more than once, and if you don’t clear the list of occurrences with `OnCalendar=`, the other assignment appends to the list instead of overriding the original assignment.